# Is it possible to overwrite the etcd quorum?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

Due to customer's requirements, I have to install k8s on two nodes(there's only two available nodes so adding another one is not an option). In this situation, setting up etcd in only one node would cause a problem if that node went down; however, setting up a etcd cluster(etcd for each node) would still not solve the problem since if one node went down, etcd cluster would not be able to achieve the majority vote for the quorum. So I was wondering if it would be possible to override the "majority rule" for the quorum so that quorum could just be 1? Or would there be any other way to solve this

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot force it to lie to itself. What you see is what you get, two nodes provide the same redundancy as one.